# Angular 4: Getting windows credentials popup

Tags: angular

I was working on a angular project (intranet) and used asp .net  web api for getting data. I had used integrated windows authentication which I don't know how credentials are passed to iis server and authentication is being done. Used HttpClient  and used withCredentials set to to true & Everything works fine - every https get post requests works fine for like 20 min and after that I get an 401 unauthorized response from server and the browser prompts for windows credentials.

- Need some help in determining how and where I can verify that credentials are being passed
- Also why for first few requests it won't prompt after that it prompts.
  We haven't used any session management.

Also when I open fiddler thinking that there I can check for any failure requests details, I won't get any failure requests and windows credentials popup doesn't appear at all.

This is my first question in SOF so please excuse me for the way I have asked , if any details needed pls ask for it I'll provide.